# how to use curried type arguments in matryoshka

Tags: scala

After reading [this excellent intro](http://akmetiuk.com/posts/2017-03-10-matryoshka-intro.html) about [matryoshka](https://github.com/slamdata/matryoshka), I tried to transform `IntList` into a generic list (I kept the name `IntList` in the example below)

```
 sealed trait IntList[+H, +A]
 case class Cons[A](head: H, tail: A) extends IntList[H, A]
 case object Empty extends IntList[Nothing, Nothing]

 implicit def intListFunct[H]: Functor[IntList[H, ?]] = new Functor[IntList[H, ?]] {
   def map[A, B](fa: IntList[H, A])(f: A => B): IntList[H, B] = fa match {
     case Cons(head, tail) => Cons(head, f(tail))
     case Empty => Empty
   }
 }

 def lst[T](implicit T: Corecursive.Aux[T, IntList[Int, ?]]): T =
   Cons(
     1,
     Cons(
       2,
       Cons(
         3,
         Empty.embed
       ).embed
     ).embed
   ).embed

 def sumList[T](l: T)(implicit T: Recursive.Aux[T, IntList[Int, ?]]): Int = l.cata[Int] {
   case Cons(head, tail) => head + tail
   case Empty => 0
 }

 val listRes = sumList(lst[Fix[IntList[Int, ?]]])
```

but it doesn't compile I get this error:

```
[error] /Users/caente1/workshop/graphs/src/main/scala/graph.scala:40: could not find implicit value for parameter T: matryoshka.Corecursive.Aux[matryoshka.data.Fix[[β$4$]common.lists.package.IntList[Int,β$4$]],[β$2$]common.lists.package.IntList[Int,β$2$]]
[error]   val listRes = sumList(lst[Fix[IntList[Int, ?]]])
```

So I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I can't get my head around it yet, what would be better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In the "Examples revisited" section of that guide, it is said to apply [SI2712 fix](https://github.com/milessabin/si2712fix-plugin) - have you done that? Just tried your example in the command line, it worked.